# How to do batch inference on Hugging face pretrained models?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, machine-translation, huggingface

I want to do batch inference on MarianMT model. Here's the code:

```
from transformers import MarianTokenizer
tokenizer = MarianTokenizer.from_pretrained('Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-de')
src_texts = [ "I am a small frog.", "Tom asked his teacher for advice."]
tgt_texts = ["Ich bin ein kleiner Frosch.", "Tom bat seinen Lehrer um Rat."]  # optional
inputs = tokenizer(src_texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
    labels = tokenizer(tgt_texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
inputs["labels"] = labels["input_ids"]
outputs = model(**inputs)
```

How do I do batch inference?